# Java user.home in launcher VM parameters

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to include a .vmoptions file from the user home directory. I have tried `"-include-options ${launcher:sys.userHome}/.vmoptions"` And it doesn't work. Does anybody have a solution?

I was able to view the log and it contains this link.

```
adding vmoptions from <${launcher:sys.userHome}/.vmoptions> (00000000)
```

I have also tried the following with no luck.

```
${USERPROFILE}
${APPDATA}
%USERPROFILE%
%APPDATA%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Unfortunately version 4.2 has a bug which makes this inoperable. In version 6.0.2, `${USERPROFILE}` works great.